# VUE: SFC - use markdown in <docs> tag - vite throwing eror

Tags: vuejs2, vite

So I inherited an old (Vue 2) app that uses [Styleguidist](https://vue-styleguidist.github.io/) for creating style guide and documenting components...

It was running extra slow so my first task was to upgrade to using vite instead of webpack. Almost there... fixed almost all the issue, the one is outstanding though... this app uses this format of *.vue components

````
<template>...</template>
<script>...</script>
<style>...</style>
<docs>
  Example of usage
  ```jsx
  <MyComponent>...</MyComponent>
</docs>
````

where content inside  is markdown, so one can write nicer documentation with code example

Now, vite is complaining that I am trying to use jsx (where I am not)...

this is the error

> 3:36:36 PM [vite] Internal server error: Failed to parse source for
> import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you
> are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx
> extension.   Plugin: vite:import-analysis

So what am I to do? How do I tell VITE to ignore that part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution, as posted [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/9301#discussioncomment-3224059), is to create a small Vite plugin that ignores the `<docs>` blocks.

Add this to `vite.config.js`:

```js
const vueDocsPlugin = {
    name: 'vue-docs',
    transform(code, id) {
        if (!/vue&type=docs/.test(id))
            return;
        return `export default ''`;
    }
};
```

Then add the plugin to the `plugins` array:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        // vue() will be here...
        vueDocsPlugin,
    ],
});
```

Comment: seems to work! thank you. this really should be documented better in the vite docs, especially with vitepress on the rise.